# MySQL Error: Duplicate entry for Primary Key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, duplicates

SQL query:

**Dumping data for table `new_recipe`**

```
INSERT INTO `new_recipe` (`id`, `post_title`, `post_image`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_desc`) VALUES
(4, 'Daal Chawal', 'DDAa.jpg', 'Asad Khan', '2016-05-29', '\r\n Gujranwala agr pyara na hota\r\n\r\nGulshan Iqbal Park ka nizara na hota\r\n\r\nBypass pr ishara na hota\r\n\r\nSialkoti drwazy ka shara na hota\r\n\r\nPace pr janay ka mode dobara na hota\r\n\r\nBashir k dal chawal ka swad krara na hota\r\n\r\nsb Sattelite Town Girls Collage ka ksoor hai\r\n\r\nw\r\na Gujranwala ka koi larrka aawara na hota("\r\n\r\nGeo Gujranwala'),
(5, 'Daal Makhani', 'maxresdefault.jpg', 'Waqas Ali', '2016-05-29', '\r\n   siosadflwq r0ewlk hopxcyfsajr w4dfwsaf654wq13\r\nt1sd3v5sa +et5wq+e f80w+e5t+eqd7fv+6sd1v 3x4c6\r\n5v321d35g 02df6s0+52wer+t q032va0sd')
MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This is my MYSQL QUERY

**Table structure for table `new_recipe`**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_recipe (
  id int(10) NOT NULL,
  post_title varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  post_image varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  post_author varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  post_date date NOT NULL,
  post_desc text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

**Dumping data for table `new_recipe`**

```
INSERT INTO `new_recipe` (`id`, `post_title`, `post_image`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_desc`) VALUES
(4, 'Daal Chawal', 'DDAa.jpg', 'Asad Khan', '2016-05-29', '\r\n Gujranwala agr pyara na hota\r\n\r\nGulshan Iqbal Park ka nizara na hota\r\n\r\nBypass pr ishara na hota\r\n\r\nSialkoti drwazy ka shara na hota\r\n\r\nPace pr janay ka mode dobara na hota\r\n\r\nBashir k dal chawal ka swad krara na hota\r\n\r\nsb Sattelite Town Girls Collage ka ksoor hai\r\n\r\nw\r\na Gujranwala ka koi larrka aawara na hota("\r\n\r\nGeo Gujranwala'),
(5, 'Daal Makhani', 'maxresdefault.jpg', 'Waqas Ali', '2016-05-29', '\r\n   siosadflwq r0ewlk hopxcyfsajr w4dfwsaf654wq13\r\nt1sd3v5sa +et5wq+e f80w+e5t+eqd7fv+6sd1v 3x4c6\r\n5v321d35g 02df6s0+52wer+t q032va0sd');
```

[Image of the PHPmyadmin error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1q4P.png)`

Comment: please share the result of: `SELECT * FROM new_recipe WHERE id = 4;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second dumping database you use same id it's already exist in 'new_recipe' that's why it display duplicate entry.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_recipe (
                        id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
                        post_title varchar(250) NOT NULL,
                        post_image varchar(250) NOT NULL,
                        post_author varchar(250) NOT NULL,
                        post_date date NOT NULL,
                        post_desc text NOT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (id)
                       ) AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `new_recipe` (`id`, `post_title`, `post_image`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_desc`) VALUES
('', 'Daal Chawal', 'DDAa.jpg', 'Asad Khan', '2016-05-29', '\r\n Gujranwala agr pyara na hota\r\n\r\nGulshan Iqbal Park ka nizara na hota\r\n\r\nBypass pr ishara na hota\r\n\r\nSialkoti drwazy ka shara na hota\r\n\r\nPace pr janay ka mode dobara na hota\r\n\r\nBashir k dal chawal ka swad krara na hota\r\n\r\nsb Sattelite Town Girls Collage ka ksoor hai\r\n\r\nw\r\na Gujranwala ka koi larrka aawara na hota("\r\n\r\nGeo Gujranwala'),
('', 'Daal Makhani', 'maxresdefault.jpg', 'Waqas Ali', '2016-05-29', '\r\n   siosadflwq r0ewlk hopxcyfsajr w4dfwsaf654wq13\r\nt1sd3v5sa +et5wq+e f80w+e5t+eqd7fv+6sd1v 3x4c6\r\n5v321d35g 02df6s0+52wer+t q032va0sd');
```

add auto increment and during insert data blank the id it's auto increment.