# MYSQL PHP Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in

Tags: php, mysql

Good day, friends! I'm facing this error regarding MYSQL queries on a simple website ( self-learning)...

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in C:\xampp\htdocs\recipe\new.php:116 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\recipe\new.php(116): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'insert into new...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\recipe\new.php on line 116

This is the image of the codes on line 116, you may have a look
[image]

image of the web page where the error is displaying
[image]

Previously I was on my mac (mamp),and it said that error was coming from the sql file,

SQL queries:

```
 Database: `recipes`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `new_recipe`
--

CREATE TABLE `new_recipe` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `post_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `post_image` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `post_author` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `post_date` date NOT NULL,
  `post_desc` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `new_recipe`
--

INSERT INTO `new_recipe` (`id`, `post_title`, `post_image`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_desc`) VALUES

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_contact`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbl_contact` (
  `tbl_contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_message` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_contact`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_contact` (`tbl_contact_id`, `fullname`, `email`, `user_message`) VALUES

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `f_name` text NOT NULL,
  `l_name` text NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `c_email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `c_pass` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `u_name` text NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` text NOT NULL,
  `state` text NOT NULL,
  `country` text NOT NULL,
  `gender` text NOT NULL,
  `p_o` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `f_name`, `l_name`, `email`, `c_email`, `pass`, `c_pass`, `u_name`, `address`, `date_of_birth`, `city`, `state`, `country`, `gender`, `p_o`) VALUES

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `new_recipe`
--
ALTER TABLE `new_recipe`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tbl_contact`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_contact`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tbl_contact_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbl_contact`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_contact`
  MODIFY `tbl_contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=32;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

Comment: Code in the question, not as an image, please.

Comment: `id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you, Now can you help me solve the error that I'm facing please

Comment: @ELCapitan it is primary key auto increment problem...

Comment: This line in your dump/restore `INSERT INTO \`users\` (\`user_id\`, \`f_name\`, \`l_name\`, \`email\`, \`c_email\`, \`pass\`, \`c_pass\`, \`u_name\`, \`address\`, \`date_of_birth\`, \`city\`, \`state\`, \`country\`, \`gender\`, \`p_o\`) VALUES` Makes me think the file has been corrupted by a carless edit

Comment: @ELCapitan You have given the full structure of the database instead of the table of which you are facing the problem...  so please provide the query on which line you are facing the issue... so, it can be solved quickly...

Comment: also, check in ID column in database there should be no id with the same number or also no id should be 0

Comment: Could be why the ALTER commands setting AUTOINCREMENT did not get actioned, although its likely you **also** didnt show all of that dump file **or** also corrupted the bottom of the file somehow

Comment: But basically you show us PART of a dump restore file **which definitely contains some issues** which could explain why your tables do not have AUTOINCREMENT set when they should have

Comment: **And** you already asked this question **and accepted an answer** [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399024/mysql-error-duplicate-entry-for-primary-key)

Comment: THANK YOU ALL.
especially @RiggsFolly...

Answer (score 3):

Your `new_recipe` table is not incrementing the ID by default, so it keeps trying to insert 0.

```
CREATE TABLE `new_recipe` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like your new_recipe table doesn't have AUTO_INCREMENT declared

Comment: I see you are short of reps, but this is really just a comment. This type of  answer attracts downvotes or gets flagged
___I did not DV___ and if that happens you will loose rep points and take longer to get to the 50 reps you need to comment on any question.
Until then, stick to questions that are well asked and therefore easily answered without
needing clarification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Answer (score 0):

make primary key set auto-increment.

```
   CREATE TABLE `new_recipe` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`, primary key(id)
```

Also, scan check previous entry in table new_recipe, there should be no previous entry with id = 0 and all id should have a unique number.

if everything is fine then check SQL mode
open phpmyadmin go to variable tab then search for sql mode edit it and make it blank...
it will not set permanently so don't worry. to set sql mode permanently you need to edit cnf file of mysql.